# QTreeWidget avoid default selection of new item

Tags: qt

So QTreeWidget seems to default to select the newest item inserted into it. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? I have looked at the documentation but could not find anything. I would instead like to keep the focus on the first item inserted into the QTreeWidget.

This is how I insert things into my tree

```
void insertIntoTree(QTreeWidget *tree)
for (int i = 0; i < streams.count(); i++) {
            tree->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
            quint64 key = streams.keys().at(i);
            const StreamInfo &info = streams.value(key);

            QTreeWidgetItem* parent = makeItem(StreamId::calcName(key), true);
            tree->addTopLevelItem(parent);
            parent->setSelected(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem and where we can see how do you insert new item in QTreeWidget.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it by creating a minimal-reproducible-example and I can not reproduce your behavior. If have to explicitly set the item being selected, if I want to achieve your described behavior.

I suggest that you learn how to create minimal-reproducible-examples, it is really fun and most of the time, they are stunningly small and fast-written.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QTreeWidget>

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto frame = new QFrame;
    frame->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    auto widget = new QTreeWidget;
    auto btn = new QPushButton("Add");
    frame->layout()->addWidget(widget);
    frame->layout()->addWidget(btn);
    btn->connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]()  {
        auto item = new QTreeWidgetItem;
        item->setData(0, Qt::ItemDataRole::DisplayRole, "Item");
        widget->addTopLevelItem(item);
        // item->setSelected(true); // Order ist important to active selection
    });
    frame->show();
    app.exec();
}
```

Comment: 'It is really fun' :-) *and most of the time, they result in the question being answered before it is asked* - which is why we have so few good examples for MCVEs here on SO...

Comment: @MartinHennings: That's a very good point. I just wanted to show, that creating a MCVE is not just being helpful here on SO, but also for every day work.

Comment: Oops. I found the error I was calling parent->setSelected(true);

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic: Hilarious!